# Bash piping answer in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, pipe

In a bash script, I want to know know how to pipe in answers like for example:

```
ssh -l username -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id host.com < yes
```

The ssh connection would ask if I would like to continue the connection and I want to pipe in the answer yes automatically and enter me in, but my script "< yes" doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to properly type and pipe the response "yes" in bash under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

You usually are only asked if you want to connect when ssh is performing host key checking.  Instead of trying to disable by using expect or a pipe, perhaps you could just disable it in your ssh configuration.

Add `StrictHostKeyChecking no` to your `~/.ssh/config`, and ssh will no longer ask you if you want to connect, it will just connect.

Comment: +1 for solving the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -l username -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id host.com` to avoid the question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should have tried this, instead of `< yes`:

```
$ echo "yes" | ssh -l username -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id host.com
```

Secondly, not even this will work because ssh doesn't read the answer from stdin, it reads it directly from the terminal, so you'll need something like [Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/):

```
$ expect -c 'spawn dislocate ssh -l username -i /home/ciupicri/.ssh/id_rsa test3
expect {
    "(yes/no)? " {
        send "yes\n"
        expect {
            "Warn" exit
        }
    }
}'
$ dislocate
```

*dislocate* is a command that comes with Expect (at least on Fedora). Answer with `y` when asked `connect? [y]`.

You could also try using [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/), a pure Python Expect-like module. Check
out its *hive.py* and *sshls.py* examples.

Comment: do you mind giving me an example?